# how to force __callStatic for unknown static methods even if instance method with the same name exists?

Tags: php, static, magic-methods

I've some class with this signature (PHP 5.3):

```
class a {

    public static function __callStatic($name) {
        echo "unknown static method $name called";
    }

    public function foo() {
        echo "instance method foo called";
    }

}
```

It does this:

```
a::not_known();
// unknown static method not_known called -- CORRECT

$obj = new a();
$obj->foo();
// instance method foo called -- CORRECT

a::foo();
// instance method foo called -- WRONG
// should be: unknown static method foo called
```

Is there any way I can prevent the call to the instance method but use the `__callStatic` for unknown static methods? If I call a static method, I want a static method to run ...

---

**Edit**: Why why the answer below from SergeS does not work (php 5.3.2):

```
class a {
    public $name = "a";

    function ident() {
        if( !is_object( $this )) { 
            echo "I am STATIC class a\n";
        } else {
            echo "I am INSTANCE class a\n";
            echo "\$this has name: $this->name\n";
        }
    }
}

class b {
    public $name = "b";

    function test() {
        a::ident();
    }
}

a::ident();
$a = new a();
$a->ident();

$b = new b();
$b->test();
```

gives the following output:

```
a::ident();  --> I am STATIC class a // correct
$a->ident(); --> I am INSTANCE class a // correct
                 $this has name: a // correct
$b->test();  --> I am INSTANCE class a // wrong! should be 'STATIC class a'
                 $this has name: b // wrong! $this is an instance of 'b'!
```

In the last call, the method `ident` of class `a` is called statically in an instance of `b`. And this passes the instance of `b` as `$this` to the method of `a`, which is obviously dead wrong!

Comment: Zend/PHP isn't strict about the method declaration. Normal methods implicitly can double as static, because in scripting languages there is no reason they couldn't.

Comment: @mario There is one very importang reason: `$this` is not defined in static method. It makes more sense the other way round (calling static methods non-static).

Comment: @KingCrunch In this variation the context probing as SergeS exampled is applicable however, even if less common or useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is during to definition of __callStatic - it will be called if method with this name is not reachable - but a::foo is (no matter it is or it is not static) - so, if you want to keep this construct, put this at beginning of foo method :

```
if( is_object( $this )) if( $this instanceof a ) { 
    // Do non-static
    return;
} 
// Do static here
```

PS Edit example to make sure it will be same instance too - but this is not always corrct as answer for select static or non-stati call because if i have this hierarchy

Class A -> Class B -> Class C ( Class C implements both A and B ), if i want to call specific method from A i will write A::method ( similiar to specific method in B by calling B::method OR parent::method )

Comment: Neat trick worth +1 except... if ((!isset($this)) || (!is_object($this)) || (!is_a($this,__CLASS__))) { is safer and without errors

Comment: @MarkBaker `$this` can _never_ be anything else than an object of the class (or subclass), or `null`. http://ideone.com/CXnsC Just `isset($this)` should do it (because `isset($a = null) == false` and it prevents you from "not defined"-messages)

Comment: Simply using if(!is_object($this)) gives me an "Undefined variable: this" notice (at least in PHP 5.3.8)

Comment: I added an example to my question where this gives really wrong results imo.

Comment: That isn't tricky - after test on 'is_object( $this )' add this '$this instanceof a'. It is from nature oh php ( a::function in your case is same as parent::function , so php keeps $this as instance of b )

Comment: Mark Baker - you can ignore it or test using isset

Comment: I still wonder: Is the example I provided in my question a bug of PHP or is it reasonably it works like this?

Comment: It is somwhere between, because such model is a bit "strange" ( I never used the same method name for both static and nonstatic function ) - but it is enough to check instance as i wrote in comment ( and edited post ). But I recommend you to review your object model, so there is no confusions like this

Comment: well, it is a corner case, yes ... I thought more about it, and for me it is already a bug that instance-methods with the same name are called instead of `__callStatic`, when I want to call a static function which doesn't exists. Whatever. I came around it (it was just a possible helper for me anyway).